# Can I embed a Facebook video and be notified when it starts playing (cross-platform)

Tags: javascript, facebook, video

I would like to embed a Facebook video on a webpage and listen to its playback events.

On pages such as https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=ID where ID is the video ID, I am able to embed the post by clicking "embed post" at the bottom right. For this matter, the FB javascript API is loaded and replaces the link with an iframe showing the post containing the playable video.

Fine, but do you see any solution to be notified (javascript callback) when the video starts, and/or reached a certain cue point? Like with the [Youtube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) or Javascript API.

I have tried things like `FB.Event.subscribe('video.play', callback);` since the embeddable snippet loads the FB api providing the global `FB` object, but with no success...

And by embedding the video, I don't mean just the MP4 file, but the whole player, so that Facebook actually counts a view ;)

Comment: No there is no API's for that

Comment: I know that, I'm just wondering if it's still possible

Comment: No it is not possible